# CVE-2014-6271 bash patch trouble

Tags: bash, security

I have a Ubuntu [EDIT] 12.04.4 LTS server that is vulnerable to the recent bash remote executable exploit. Ubuntu says they have released [a patch here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2362-1/)
I have run a

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but when I run

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'  bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

I still get

```
vulnerable
this is a test
```

I have also tried rebooting with no difference. Is there a problem with the test or is there another step for patching?

==============

UPDATE:

1) updated the server to 14.04.1

2) reconfigured sources.list for default trusty mirrors including security.ubuntu.com, pulled updates

3) rebooted

Compared against a fresh 14.04.1 install (with security updates downloaded on install) which passes testing.

However on original server test fails.

Comment: Also echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]} returns 25 (the patched version). Is the patch failing the test?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy bash` to your question.

Comment: my network has privately hosted mirrors - would that be the issue?

Comment: but essentially -    
  Installed: 4.2-2ubuntu2.1
  Candidate: 4.2-2ubuntu2.1
Version table:
 *** 4.2-2ubuntu2.1 0

Comment: It's a bare server so I'm updating to 14.04 to see if that fixes it.

Comment: The fixed version for 12.04 is 4.2-2ubuntu2.2, for 14.04 it's 4.3-7ubuntu1.1 Make sure you have `security.ubuntu.com` in your package sources.

Comment: Added security mirrors in format from https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/configuration.html and pulled down no new updates HOWEVER, patch reset to 4.3.0 (echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]} so going to try re-patching manually.

Comment: Had to use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bash` for the patch to be applied to 12.04 myself. The official method for updating does not seem to work. That's pretty bad if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

You must upgrade to 12.04.5, 12.04.4 went EOL aug 8th, try apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed patch on 14.04:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'  bash -c "echo this is a test"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
this is a test
$
```